# Private Form's Add-On for GAFE users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to develop private Forms Add-On for schools working with GAFE (the free-be version)

It cannot be listed on the G-suite Marketplace as it 
private to our application.

It cannot be deployed on the schools different GAFE domains being different domain and rejected by by GAFE.

Trying to deploy via separate cloned project on each of the GAFE domains fails as it requires standard GCP project association which is not possible with GAFE account.

How can this be accomplished ?

Comment: If you clone an Add-on - for each domain you need to associate the respective copy of the script  to a GCP project created on that domain and on each domain the Add-On has to go through the publishing process with the G Suite Marketplace SDK (specifying visibility:My domain).

Comment: Can you associate GCP project with a GAFE account ?

Comment: If you can access https://console.cloud.google.com/ and create projects there, than you can also associate as Apps Script with his project by going from the Apps Script editor on `Resources - > Cloud Platform project...`

Comment: Using the GAFE account I get the error : You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page. Using different account (my developer account) this is fine - however then it is not possible to associate my GCP project with the script project.

Comment: Do you get this error when simply going to  console.cloud.google.com ?

Comment: Yes. It is fine when I log in with my my developer account, however when I switch to the GAFE account I get this error  message, the GAFE account is administrator of the domain.